# Javafx Task running intermittently

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx-8

I'm running FX8 (JDK8_u25) and have the following code

```
private void initializeBrokerCommunication()
{
    System.out.println("0");
    try {
        Task<List<Integer>> initTask = new Task<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<Integer> call() throws Exception
            {
                System.out.println("1");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                DateTime upperBound = new DateTime(masterXAxis.getUpperBound());
                DateTime lowerBound = new DateTime(masterXAxis.getLowerBound());
                int seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(lowerBound, upperBound).getSeconds();
                lowerBound = lowerBound.minusSeconds(seconds);
                System.out.println("2");
                return broker.getDeviceData(null, upperBound.toDate(), lowerBound.toDate(), true);

            }
        };
        // setOnSucceeded ensures that the method processHistoricData runs on the Fx thread.
        initTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            System.out.println("3");
            processHistoricData(initTask.valueProperty().getValue(), true);
        });
        // submit the task and the scheduler decides when to run it.
        scheduler.submit(initTask);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("4");
}
```

`scheduler` is a `ScheduledExecutorService` object and is initialized as follows
`ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);`

initializeBrokerCommunication() method is wrapped in a class that extends Application class. Multiple runs of my class produces different outputs each time.

`0-4-1-2-3` is what I expect, but sometimes I see `0-4` being printed and don't see `1-2-3` even being printed.

Any pointers as to why task runs intermittently.

Comment: How many times do they get printed?

Comment: initializeBrokerCommunication() is called once and this task is created once. sysouts are printed once. To clarify this, I run my program multiple times and see the output 0-4 sometimes and 0-4-1-2-3 sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean by `1, 2 and 3 gets printed intermittently`?

Comment: I should have explained a little more. Multiple runs of my program produces the outputs `0-4` or `0-4-1-2-3`.

Comment: That is pretty obvious. The reason for it is the new thread may take some time to get spawn. In the mean time, the main thread completes it's execution and prints `4`

Comment: Still 1-2-3 should be printed sometime in the future, I don't see that ever happen

Comment: Yes they must be. Make sure that the task is not blocked by the method calls made by you inside the `call()`. You can drop a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better solutions to your problem.

Comment: What kind of `Executor` is `scheduler`?

Comment: Is it possible you are somehow using all the threads available to the `scheduler` and they are all getting blocked? I think you will have to create an MCVE to be able to get help with this, as `ItachiUchiha` suggests.

Comment: I found my problem. The issue is not with the `ExecutorService` or the `Task` but this line of code `masterXAxis.getLowerBound()`. When I make a call to get the lowerBound, the masterXAxis has not been completely laid/rendered, its is in the process of being rendered hence the task runs intermittently.